# How to fix this Rstan/R code for a MCMC from an AR(1) model?

Tags: r, mcmc, stan

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong with my Rstan code... Note that the data is just some simulated data.

I receive the following error message when I run the ar1_stan_fit:

> Error in if (nchar(CXX) == 0) { : argument is of length zero
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In system2(file.path(R.home(component = "bin"), "R"), args = paste("CMD config",  :
>     running command ''/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' CMD config CXX14 2>/dev/null' had status 1"

Any comments?

Code:

```
    library(rstan)
    rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)
    options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())

    ar1.stan <- '
    data {
      int<lower=0> N;
      vector[N] y;
    }

    parameters {
      real mu;
      real phi;
      real<lower=0> sigma;
    } 

    model {
    // Priors
      sigma ~ normal(0, 1);
      mu ~ normal(0, 1);
      phi ~ normal(0, 1);

    // Model
      for (n in 2:N)
      y[n] ~ normal(mu + phi * y[n-1], sigma);
    }'


   AR1_1 <- ar_sim(0.3)

   data <- list(N = 200, y = AR1_1)

   ar1_stan_fit <- stan(model_code = ar1.stan, data = data)
```

Comment: Where is the ar_sim function coming from?

Comment: @Dason That is just some simulation function I did before:  
ar_sim<-function(phi){
  x <- vector("numeric", T)  
  x[1] <- mu  
  for (t in 2:T){  
    x[t] <- mu + phi * (x[t-1] - mu) + rnorm(1, 0, sqrt(sigma_sq))  
  }  
  print(x)  
}

Comment: You need to include all relevant code in your question

Comment: Also T was never a parameter or defined in your function. That's relevant too.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that your C++ compiler is not configured correctly. That is unrelated to the Stan code.

Comment: Thanks @BenGoodrich! I found the issue. I had to reinstall Xcode!